# Object-oriented programming in Go -- use "new" keyword or nah?

Tags: oop, go

I am learning Go, and I have a question based on the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Vector struct {
    x, y, z int
}

func VectorFactory(x,y,z int) *Vector {
    return &Vector{x, y, z}
}

func main() {
    vect := VectorFactory(1, 2, 3)
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", (vect.x * vect.y * vect.z))
}
```

Here I've defined a type `Vector` with `x`, `y`, and `z`, and I've defined function `VectorFactory` which declares a pointer to a `Vector` and returns that pointer. I use this function to create a new `Vector` named `vect`.

- Is this bad code? Should I be using the `new` keyword rather than building a `Factory`?
- Do I need to `delete` the `Vector` after using it, like in C++? If so, how?

Thanks. I'm still waiting for my Go book to be delivered.

Comment: Quick one: Code looks fine, though a Factory seems to be a bit of an overkill in this case – you could simply create a new instance by using a literal in place, so `vect:= Vector{x:1,y:2,z:3}`. Other than that, I'd suggest using labels for initializing structs(like I did), as this is likely to reduce errors in the long run.

Comment: Putting aside the need for creating a "factory" (per previous comment), idiomatic name for it would be `NewVector`. `&Vector{...}` is fine as well, probably nobody would really use `new` keyword here (it's usually useful for built-in types like `map` or `chan`). Also, no need to delete anything, Go has garbage collector. I can feel your impatience to learn a new language, but reading a Go (on its way!) book or https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html will be very helpful to start being a gopher. Check out everything under https://golang.org/doc really and _voilà!_

Comment: "Constructors" in Go are named "NewVector" and not "VectorFactory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer `NewThing` to `ThingFactory`.

Don't make a `NewThing` function, unless you have complex initialisation, or you're intentionally not exporting parts of a struct. Selectively setting only parts of a struct is not complex, that can be accomplished by using labels. Complex would be things like "the value of slot Q depends on what the value of slot Zorb is". Unexported struct fields can be useful for information hiding, but should be used with care.

Go is garbage-collected, any piece of data that is not referenced is eligible to be collected. Start out y not worrying about it, then get to a point where you ensure you clean up any reference to data you're no longer interested in so as to avoid accidental liveness ("accidental liveness" is essentially the GC equivalent of "memory leak").

If you expect to print your data structures frequently, consider making a `String` method for them (this is not exactly corresponding to the print you do, but might be generally more useful for a vector):

```
func (v Vector) String() string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("V<%d, %d, %d>", v.x v.y, v.z);
}
```

Unless "vect" really means something to you, prefer either "v" or "vector" as a name.